# Joining objects in an array for animation with Boolean stumping me a bit

Tags: modifiers

I'm relatively new to Blender, though rapidly getting comfortable (my background came from CAD/CAM systems). I have a relatively simple architectural project I'm working on where I am creating posts and railings. I first created a wrought iron post that I set in an array of three posts. Between the posts I put a top and bottom rail then added a single picket that I set to array. So far so good. I wanted to use a Boolean to animate that setup disappearing for a new use of the space by the construction contractor. I decided that it would be quicker (probably less overhead) to join the entire group and have the Boolean work on the group. When I join all the items, only the original item in the array appears, all the others disappear. I get very stubborn about finding a solution ( I wrote several technical manuals for CAD/CAM systems and tend to dig deep into programs for solutions first before turning to help). So, before I spend any more hours digging through manuals, and tutorials for something that may not exist, am I correct in assuming that only the original mesh in an array actually physically exists and the others are ghosts that can't be joined? Or am I missing a setting that lets me grab all of them? Thanks.

Comment: *"only the original mesh in an array actually physically exists and the others are ghosts"* that is more or less correct (I'd call "ghosts" as "unexisting geometry yet") only before modifier is not applied (that Apply button) which will make its modifications real. Note that modifiers are non-destructive workflow, they don't change anything irreversibly. When joining, active / selected last object will be the one which modifiers will be used for the joined object.

Comment: "*my background came from CAD/CAM systems*" in the long run, if you want to avoid headaches, you should really ditch the Boolean-based workflow

Comment: Although you can use booleans at the bottom of the modifier list, you can also copy modifiers between objects.

Comment: Thanks! I just blew right past applying the modifier, once I did everything worked smooth